# Keeping input value for validation in Vue JS

Tags: forms, validation, vue.js, vuex

Making login function with string validation with VueJS

Here is my code: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuexinputvalue-bo3yd)

Problem occurs in this follow,

1. both input keep with empty and click `Login` button

   error msg `Enter your username` and `Enter your password` appear
2. enter something in one of these input

   ex) entering xxxx in `password` area
3. click `Login` button

**Problem happens**

4. value of `password` input area disappears

I'd like to keep value in input box every time `Login` button clicked till both input value are correct.

How can I fix it?

Form validation function are written in `Login.vue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register (add) `value` prop in `Form.vue` component:

```
props: {
// ...your registered props
// add below
  value: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
},
```

Why?

Because right now it is not reactive. So when parent changes `value` child component does not react.

Comment: You are right. Adding `value` in `props` makes problem solved. Thanks a lot for your help!